# Make Nodemon use old version on crash

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Let's say you are developing some Node application and your code crashed because of a syntax error or similar. How can you make Nodemon not switch to the new version and keep running the old version until the new version does not cause a crash.

Comment: What is "old version" and "new version" are you changing your code? Do you not want Nodemon to restart your app?

Comment: @LucaKiebel Old version is the source code that ran before hot reloading on file change, new version is the new change that caused the crash.